# redirecting qt output to /dev/fb2 on linux

Tags: embedded-linux

I am trying to redirect the Qt output to /dev/fb2 which is mapped to LVDS display. I am not able to do.Primary display is /dev/fb0 which is mapped to HDMI display. I am using freescale IMX6 saberautoboard.I have tried using the following command

./qtapp -qws -display Linux:/dev/fb2. But I am getting following error. 
Linux: driver not found Aborted

Please help me regarding this.

Regards,
Shivaraj

Comment: Which version of Qt ?

Answer (score 0):

extract from : [Qt embedded displaymanagement](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embedded-displaymanagement.html)

Qt for Embedded Linux provides drivers for the Linux framebuffer, the virtual framebuffer, transformed screens, VNC servers and multi screens. Run the configure script to list the available drivers:

`./configure -help`

In the default Qt configuration, only an unaccelerated Linux framebuffer driver (/dev/fb0) is enabled. The various drivers can be enabled and disabled using the configure script. For example:

`./configure -qt-gfx-transformed`

Check if you can enable /dev/fbX here

Comment: I tried, it again directs the output to primary device. QT version is 4.8.2

Comment: that was for Qt5.2, I've improved answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the guidance. But with the below command I see the output of Qt application is getting redirected to /dev/fb2 which is mapped to secondary device. Command is as follows ./qtapplication -qws -display Linuxfb:/dev/fb2:enable=1